# Drawing VBO with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been trying to set up VBO insteath of just glBegin(GLenum mode)...
And I don't get any compiler errors or crashes when I try to run it, but I also doesn't see the object...
I'm trying to draw a cube. So I initialized it and checked the values of my vertices in the debugger. And they are all fine. I then assign them using this code.
Here is all my rendering code. I see the green and the red quads, but not the cube object.

```
void Window::render() {
//Render scene
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//glRotatef(rotY, 1, 0, 0);
//glRotatef(rotX, 0, 1, 0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
glEnd();


cube1->render();

//Render interface
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glOrtho(0, windowResolution->w, windowResolution->h, 0, 1, -1);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
glEnd();
}

void Cube::render() {
updateVBO();

//Set vertex pointer
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

//Set color pointer
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

//Clear buffers
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);
}

void Cube::updateVBO() {
//Vertices:
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) *vertices.size(), &vertices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Colors
glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) *colors.size(), &colors.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Comment: We need much more code to see what is going on here. How should we be able to tell why nothing is drawn if we don't know what you are trying to draw, and how you are trying to do so?

Comment: Ah, okey. I'll fix that. I thought people hated long code posts so I tried to keep it small.

Comment: Well, people do hate long code pastes of _irrelevant_ code. The trick is to keep it to the absolute minimum without omitting anything of relevance. And the bare minimum here would be your drawing code, your shaders, your uniform and attribute setup and some information about the geometry data you are trying to draw.

Comment: I don't have shaders set up yet. Is that requred before I can see VBO's in the modern OpenGL?

Comment: Well, depends on how you define _modern_. Shaders are required in _core profiles_ of OpenGL. In compatibility profiles or old GL, you can still go without them. What context version are you using?

Comment: YOur code still does not show what your `vertices` and `colors` array contain. And how is your projection matrix set up? Another thing I see is that you _create 2 new VBOs per render call_, leaking ther buffer objects completely. Your program will run out of memory if you let it run long enough.

Comment: I have no idea what context version I'm using, where can I find that?
If there is memory leaks that was expected, as I find everything about using OpenGL very confusing and hard to learn. Especially after the changes to 3.0

Comment: Well, If you don't know that, you probably aren't requesting a specific version or profile. `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` will tell you waht you got. Depending on your drivers and OS, you are likely to end up with a GL 3 or 4 compatibility profile, or GL2.1.

Comment: Don't call `updateVBO()` each time you render... Only call it when an update is needed! And also, don't generate a new buffer inside the `updateVBO()`, only generate the buffer(s) once!

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns me 4.4.0, and thanks, I'll fix my updateVBO()